# $\varphi\neq0$ Kernel dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let V be a vector space of finite dimension $n$ over the field K. Let $\varphi$ be a functional on $V$, and assume $\varphi\neq0$. What is the dimension of the kernel of $\varphi$? Proof?

I think the functional $\varphi\neq 0$ means if I choose a linear function $L_{v_n}$ then $v_n\neq 0$ for $n$. If we define the functional by the inner product ${v_n,v}$, in which $v$ stands for all $v\in V$. Then the zero scalar would depend on the number of elements in $V$ that equal zero.

**Questions**:

**1)** How can I know the kernel dimension?

**2)** Is the dimension zero due to the isomorphism between the Dual space and the Vector Space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\dim\operatorname{Im}\varphi+\dim\ker\varphi=n$ and since $\dim\operatorname{Im}\varphi=1$, $\dim\ker\varphi=n-1$.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how $\dim Im\varphi=1$.

Comment: @PedroGomes Because $\operatorname{Im}\varphi$ is a vector subspace of $K$, wich is one-dimensional. But $\varphi\neq0$, and therefore $\operatorname{Im}\varphi\neq\{0\}$. So, $\operatorname{Im}\varphi=K$, which, as I wrote, has dimension $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of the kernel is $n-1$.

Since $\phi \ne 0$, there is some $u$ with $\phi(u) \ne 0$.  Now 
$V = \ker(\phi) \oplus \text{span}(u)$.